# How to copy assemblies using .NET Remoting

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

does anybody knows how to copy assemblies from one machine to another? 
My setup is WinXP, .NET Framework 2.0, I'm using.Net Remoting and I'm passing the assemblies as byte arrays, but for some reason I end up with different results. I not sure if it's an encoding issue or something like that.... here is the server side code
Any help will be apreciated!

```
    public void SaveAssembly(byte[] assm, string path) {                       
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Path);
        try{                                
            writer.AutoFlush = true;
            writer.Write(GetString(assm));                
            writer.Close();
        }
        finally{
            writer.Dispose();                
        }
    }

    static string GetString(byte[] bytes){
        char[] chars = new char[bytes.Length / sizeof(char)];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, chars, 0, bytes.Length);
        return new string(chars);
    }
```

note: I must to use Remoting in NET 2.0.
I already tried this to get the byte array but it didn't work either...

```
var base64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(assm);
var bytes  = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
```

Comment: Try with `File.ReadAllBytes` and  `File.WriteAllBytes`

Comment: Thanks L.B worked like a charm!

Comment: If you aren't forced to use .Net 2.0, I'd stick with WCF or even WebAPI. Remoting is a legacy path.

Comment: The StreamWriter is not meant for this kind of work. It is meant for adapting text to binary format. You allready have binary in your byte array. File.WriteAllBytes and File.ReadAllBytes are implemented using FileStream which a stream class that allows reading/writing bytes from/to a file.

Comment: Panos Rontogiannis, sadly, I learn it the hard way ;)

Comment: Oliver Weichhold unfortunately I have to use .NET remoting....